# How do I extract a value from a Twitter JSON array

Tags: php, json, twitter

I am creating a php script to check if a person is following me on Twitter and I am using the  [REST API Method: friendships show method](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554709/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3a-friendships-show) and using themattHarris tmhOAuth library for OAuth.

I am making the request using the following code:

```
$code=$tmhOAuth->request('GET', $tmhOAuth->url('friendships/show'), array( 'target_screen_name' => 'bob' ));

if ($code==200){  $code = json_decode($tmhOAuth->response['response'], true); }
```

The request is successful and returns similar json output as shown on the apiwiki page:

```
{"relationship": { "source": { "id": 123, "screen_name": "bob", "following": true, "followed_by": false, "notifications_enabled": false }, "target": { "id": 456, "screen_name": "jack", "following": false, "followed_by": true, "notifications_enabled": null } } }
```

**MY QUESTION**

How do I extract the following value from the array returned?

```
"id": 456,
```

Comment: You are [supposed to search before asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice): [http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=read+json+php](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=read+json+php)

Comment: Once you pass the JSON data through json_encode, it's just a regular PHP data structure. Access data in it as you would any other array or object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$code['relationship']['target']['id']
```

Look at example: http://codepad.org/KMEP5wPW

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Your codepad example helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a PHP array after it's been `json_decode`ed, right?

```
$code->relationship->target->id
```

or

```
$code['relationship']['target']['id']
```

Answer (score 0):

You already applied `json_decode()`, so the value you are talking about should be accessible by the following code:

```
$id_needed = $code['relationship']['target']['id'];
```

Because you have overwritten `$code` only when `$code == 200`, you have to assume `$code` may be something different than result from `json_decode()`.